# how to create installation log file in Target folder in wix

Tags: wix, wix3.8

i am using the following command to see the logs in wix installer.

**msiexec /i "D:\WixProjects\DFServicesWixSetup\DFServices\bin\Debug\DFServices.msi" /L*V "D:\DFServices.log"**

but this command is trying to install the msi again.

I want to execute this command from wix after finishing the installation and log file need to save in installed folder.

can any one help me on this.

Comment: Its not that clear what you are asking here, WiX is a toolset which creates Windows Installer packages, msiexec runs installer packages, so your command above will deploy the msi with a log file being created in D:\DFServices.log.  Could you update your question with a little more detail please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide in advance if you want Windows Installer to make a log file. You also need to decide in advance where it should go. If you want it to end up in the install folder then you either need to copy it there after installation or specify the install folder in advance, too.

In Windows Installer folders are controlled by properties. You can specify such properties in the command that starts installation. The name of the property for the "install folder" depends on how the installer authoring; INSTALLFOLDER is one typical name.

So, you could do this with a command like this:

```
msiexec /i "D:\WixProjects\DFServicesWixSetup\DFServices\bin\Debug\DFServices.msi" /L*V "D:\path\DFServices.log" /qb INSTALLFOLDER="D:\path"
```

The /qb switch is reduce the UI such that the user is offered the chance to change the installer folder. It may more may not be need for your installer, depending on what dialogs its UI normally shows.

So, the first step is to figure out which property sets the install folder in your installer.